# sqlite3: How to query for results where a column contains a certain substring

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

How do I select the rows of a sqlite3 database where a `TEXT` column contains a desired substring that I am searching for? I am trying to do this in python3.

The value of the column may vary across the many rows, and will not always match the substring exactly; however, the value of the column may contain the substring.

Comment: please show us sample data and expected result. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need the [`LIKE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) operator.

It uses `_` as a single-character wildcard and `%` as an any-length wildcard.
For example: `WHERE col LIKE '%foo%'` will match return any rows where `col` contains the text `foo`.
Note that `LIKE` is case-*sensitive* by default.  If you need to make it case-*insensitive*, apply `UPPER` to the searched column and the search pattern: `WHERE UPPER(col) LIKE UPPER('%foo%')`

Comment: Thanks a lot; that's what I was looking for.